# XAML: Is it possible to display the current URL in a WebView?

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, uwp, windows-10

there is a webview in my UWP app. By default the webview does not show the currently loaded contents url. Is it somehow possible to display the url as in the browser search field for instance?

For example if google is loaded in the webview i want to see the url "https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl" somewhere.

Best wishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could show the url in a textbox in the NavigationStarting event

```
void webView1_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    string url = "";
    try { url = args.Uri.ToString(); }
    finally
    {
        address.Text = url;
        appendLog(String.Format("Starting navigation to: \"{0}\".\n", url));
        pageIsLoading = true;
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationstarting.aspx